# ASP.NET RAZOR cannot capture the event

Tags: asp.net, razor

I want to get the value from the selected radio button after a user clicked on one of them and display it at the bottom, but it doesn't work.

I do not want to use **JAVASCRIPT** and **MVC**.

Please help~~~

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Contact";
    var selectedValue = "Male selected";
}


@{
    if (IsPost)
    {
        selectedValue = Request["Gender"].ToString();
    }   
 }
<div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male", true) Male
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female", false) Female
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <b>@selectedValue</b>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? have u tried javascript or jquery?

Comment: @ssilas777 Hi, I don't want to use JS, coz I want to explore the power of RAZOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use JavaScript, you will need a roundtrip to the server. Razor is not executed on the client. In fact the client never even sees the razor code in the first place.

Comment: hi Dennis, then How to do it? Could you please post some code for me?

Comment: Use JavaScript is all I can say. Or use an HTML form. If you don't know how HTML forms work, Google knows lots of great tutorials.