# So does it mean RAZOR without MVC cannot even do the event handler stuff?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am new to RAZOR and now I need to trigger an event when users clicked a button, so I can run a lines of code to handle the event.

I don't want to use it with **MVC**, and I don't want to use **JavaScript** because I only want to explore the power of RAZOR.

I was surprised when someone told me that the way of event-drive methods has been discarded in the RAZOR, that's alright. But my question is

**what is the way to handle/response a click event (in the RAZOR syntax) which is the simplest thing in the ASP.NET Web Form applications?**

The reason why I'm asking this question is I found that even the easiest thing like I want to write a fragment of code to response users' input hard to be done(or should I say there is no way to do it) in the RAZOR.

You can take a look the discussion in my previous post.
[ASP.NET RAZOR cannot capture the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423932/asp-net-razor-cannot-capture-the-event)

I hope there are some guys who can guide me through the first and tough step.

Thanks.

**Update:
It seems that there is really no way to handle the user events in any way without the help of MVC framework.  Thank you guys for your answers. I'd like to leave this post a few days longer and hopefully I could see someone post something interesting.
Thank you again.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no such thing like a click event** in Razor.

Event handling is a concept that was used in WinForms. The event model in classic ASP.NET WebForms was an effort to translate the Windows programming model to the web, which, frankly, didn't work very well. A stateful event model and web programming pretty much contradict each other.

If you want to work with events then use classic ASP.NET WebForms. If you want to embrace the web and not work against it, learn ASP.NET MVC, Razor, etc.

Don't try to fit a stateful legacy paradigm on a stateless infrastructure. This is what Microsoft did with WebForms and that is where it should stay.

Comment: thx for your explanation. I am wondering that if there is not many things I can do with only RAZOR why I can create a Web Site project with RAZOR?

Comment: You can do pretty much everything with razor, once you get used to it being a completely different paradigm. The event model is for rich client applications. If you want to build rich client applications on the web, you can use JavaScript (which again provides an event model).

Answer (score 0):

Razor is only for use with ASP.NET MVC.  You can't use it with the WebForms model, though there are some [advanced and messy scenarios](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx) where some folks mix the two.  This isn't what you want.